# Command line program for database script extraction

Tags: database, scripting

I am looking for a command line program that extracts a script containing commands for creations of all database objects (tables, views, procedures, generators, types). It should work with MySQL, Firebird, Oracle and MS SQL Server.

As a part of our automatic build process we would like to put in our SVN repository a script for database creation in an automatic fashion. Firebird comes with a tool that do what we want but we prefer a generic one so we can include as an ANT task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For SQL Server you can use the [Database Publishing Wizard](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=56e5b1c5-bf17-42e0-a410-371a838e570a&displaylang=en)
I can't help you with the other DB's, however. Good Luck.

To Script the Schema and Data

```
  sqlpubwiz script -d YourDB -S YourServer -U YourUsernam -P pwdhere C:\DestFile.sql
```

and to just script the Schema

```
  sqlpubwiz script -d YourDB -S YourServer -U YourUsernam -P pwdhere C:\DestFile.sql -schema
```